# Can multiple VLANs be provided with multicast addresses by a single MADCAP server?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp, vlan, multicast

Can a single DHCP server provide dynamic multicast addresses for hosts in many VLANs using MADCAP, just like it can provide hosts with unicast addresses via `ip-helper`? Or from a Cisco perspective, does `ip-helper` automatically proxy MADCAP as well as DHCP?

I know that Microsoft's DHCP server also implements the MADCAP protocol, so it can issue multicast addresses for applications that want to use multicast IP. However, I'm unclear on whether that is a broadcast/link-layer protocol, or whether it works by some other mechanism.

*Background: I have a WDS (Windows Deployment Services) server in one VLAN and a Microsoft DHCP server in a different VLAN. The WDS server is configured to obtain multicast addresses from DHCP, but I'm not sure if it's working and I don't know how to verify it.*